# How can I modify Node Checkout module to downgrade product instead of unpublish content?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I’m using [Commerce Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) and the **Expiration** submodule. It’s a great module but I have a problem that I can’t solve.

I have 3 products:

- product A: cost $0.1; expiration 999 years (free/stay always)
- product B: cost $1.0; expiration 1 week (upgrade content for 1 week)
- product C: cost $2.0; expiration 2 weeks (upgrade content for 2 weeks)

My problem is that when products "B" and "C" expire, the content is updated as unpublished.

What I need is that after expiration the content product is updated as an "A" product (the free version). Also need that the free product can be upgraded to "B" and "C" (for one or two weeks) but I think the way the module works is take the actual time and add the new one but I don’t want 999 years + 1 week. So I need that "A" is unlimited time but when upgrade takes the 1 or 2 weeks and when finished go back to unlimited.

Thanks in advance for help and guidance.

Comment: Eduardo, consider adding a hyperlink to the actual modules on drupal.org. That often helps a lot of people to understand which module you are talking about. OK?

Comment: OK, making progress. I suggested An edit for further improving The formatting, but trying to not change the actual meaning of your question (that would not be allowed). your last paragraph is still a little tricky (hard to read in English), but I cannot suggest a refinement of it because I would potentially change the meaning of what you are trying to ask. Can you try to further enhance the grammar of it? By the way: it got upvoted!